# Adobe Captivate - Drag and Drop | JavaScript - Sound Effect

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, adobe-captivate

I am creating an Adobe Captivate drag and drop interaction.

With the program, I am able to play sound once the "drag source" is put into the "drop target". However, I need to play a short sound effect when the user clicks to start dragging the "drag source."

I have tried using the advanced options available to me with no luck. I tried "faking" it by using invisible roll over images and invisible buttons, but I was unable to click through those to grab the "drag source".

After spending some hours on tutorial videos and articles I'm convinced that the solution lies within JavaScript. Though, my coding knowledge stops at HTML & CSS. Is anyone able to help me or point me in the right direction on this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Add a new state, DragStart, Add audio

1. Click the "drag source" object that you want to make a noise when grabbed.
2. Switch to the properties tab.
3. Add a new state > DragStart
4. Options tab > Add Audio

If anyone in the future runs into the same question as me.